# Preferable way to avoid if(condition) return true

Tags: java

I keep finding methods having code like this:

```
public boolean checkSomethingForCollection(Collection<Something> things){
    for(Something thing:things){
        boolean satisfiesCondition = check(thing);
        if(satisfiesCondition){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private static boolean check(Something something){
    //omitted...
}
```

I am fully aware of the fact that the public method will stop by reaching 'return' if the check(..) returns true, but it still looks ugly to me.

What would be preferable? Using break; instead to have one return only, or refactor to something else? Having

```
if(booleanExpression){
    return true;
}
```

just makes me sick.

Comment: how about: return booleanExpression; ? since you're looping, either you keep it as is, or you'll be changing the flow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java streams in Java 8 make this pretty easy - the [`Stream.anyMatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) method taking a predicate is *exactly* what you want. In this case you can use a method reference to create a predicate from the `check()` method.

```
public boolean checkSomethingForCollection(Collection<Something> things) {
    return things.stream().anyMatch(this::check);
}
```

Here's a short but complete example:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    private final int minLength;

    private Test(int minLength) {
        this.minLength = minLength;
    }

    public boolean checkAny(Collection<String> things) {
        return things.stream().anyMatch(this::check);
    }

    private boolean check(String x) {
        return x.length() >= minLength;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Test t = new Test(5);
        List<String> shortStrings = Arrays.asList("asd", "bcd", "foo");
        List<String> mixedStrings = Arrays.asList("asd", "bcd", "this is long", "foo");
        System.out.println(t.checkAny(shortStrings)); // false
        System.out.println(t.checkAny(mixedStrings)); // true
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't do that with a "java for each", but you can avoid it with a normal for like this :

```
boolean satisfiesCondition = false;
for (int i = 0; i < size && !satisfiesCondition; ++i) {
    satisfiesCondition = check(things[i]);
}

return satisfiesCondition;
```

Comment: though I disagree with npinti,, your !satisfiesCondition takes care of that, you do have to update the value of i, otherwise all you end up with is an endless loop

Comment: Oops, i forgot the ++i. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I haven't checked the code, but you should be able to do something like this:

```
things.stream()
    .filter(x -> check(x))
    .findFirst()
```

You can find some more information [here](http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/examples/find-element-in-list/).

Comment: ... if you are using java 8.

Comment: Of course. But it's the only version of Java which is not end of life anymore, so it's sort of implied.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `for` makes use of an iterator, you could opt to use a `while` loop instead:

```
Iterator<Something> iter = things.iterator();
boolean isValid= false;
while(iter.hasNext() && !isValid)
    isValid = check(iter.next());

return isValid;
```

That being said, I think that your current version of things is more readable.